# How to get SoapUI API into IBM Bluemix

Tags: soap, ibm-cloud, soapui

I'm trying to push an API that I created in SoapUI into Bluemix using the cloud foundary console. I first created a war file as per this blog: http://alleyfield.com/?p=51

I've managed to get the API into Bluemix, but the results aren't pleasing. In SoapUI I've tested my API and can confirm that it works perfectly. Surely there is a better way of creating an API in Bluemix having created it in SoapUI (soap/xml format.) My problem is that I don't see any options on the Bluemix page that allows for this. I've consulted the official documents, but they almost exclusively focus on sample application APIs using swagger or similar.

I've contacted IBM and they suggested I post this to Stack Overflow as the blog I mentioned is old and doesn't match Bluemix at present.

Comment: Thank you for the blog link. Not sure about `bluemix`, but, it would be helpful if you can post the specific problem with logs.

Comment: Please see if this link helps - https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/164108/pushing-a-local-java-war-to-bluemix.html

Comment: Have you looked at Bluemix API Connect? Not sure if it will help, but it's worth looking at: https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/api-connect/

Comment: Thanks. I think the issue lies with the format of the API rather than Bluemix. Perhaps I could have been clearer. It has been possible to push it into Bluemix, but the results weren't ideal i.e. it resulted in my application not being made available. My question is more about how to get a SoupUI generated API into Bluemix effectively. Should I create it within Bluemix itself?